# 'ng-repeat' re rendering creates a flicker

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to list all the "zones". It works just fine on the first rendering and even when additional data from the server is added to the existing data it works without any issues or flickers. But when the "$rootScope.zones" is assigned a new value (the user can change the sort order from Alphabetical to Proximity, which sets a new value for the $rootScope.zones in that sorting order) the whole ng-repeat list goes blank for a few seconds and then works fine again.
This is not a very big issue except in the zones I have some text with CSS bubbles around. The text disappears but the bubbles remain.

How can I set the $rootScope.zones such that it doesn't create that flicker? Alternatively, how can I make sure that the "bubbles" only appear when the text is there.

This is my ng-repeat:

```
<ion-list class="card" ng-if="$root.currentMode.zoneBroadcast == true" can-swipe="true">
      <div class="button-bar no-padding">
        <button class="button bold" ng-class="{'button-calm': sortMethod === 'Alphabetically'}" ng-click="changeSortMethod('Alphabetically')">Alphabetically</button>
        <button class="button bold" ng-class="{'button-calm': sortMethod === 'By Proximity'}" ng-click="changeSortMethod('By Proximity')">By Proximity</button>
      </div>
      <ion-item class="item no-border no-padding dark-bg" ng-repeat="zone in $root.zones track by zone.zoneName"
                ng-if="checkVisibility(zone.zoneName)">
          <div class="item-divider text-center">
              <span>
                Zone ID : <span>{{zone.zoneName}}</span>
              </span>
          </div>
          <div class="item-body" ng-class="checkIfZoneMatches(zone.zoneName) ? 'zone-broadcast-green' : parseStringToInteger(zone.Trips.length) > 0 ? 'zone-broadcast-red' : checkIfZoneCanBookIn(zone.zoneName)  ? 'zone-broadcast-yellow' : zone.Lineup.FreeList.length > 0 ? 'zone-broadcast-blue' : 'zone-broadcast-normal'">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <span ng-class="{'lineup free' : zone.Lineup.FreeList.length != 0}">{{zone.Lineup.FreeList.toString()}}</span>
                <span ng-class="{'lineup loaded' : zone.Lineup.LoadedList.length != 0}">{{zone.Lineup.LoadedList.toString()}}</span>
                <span ng-class="{'lineup accepted' : zone.Lineup.AcceptedList.length != 0}">{{zone.Lineup.AcceptedList.toString()}}</span>
                <span ng-class="{'lineup offered' : zone.Lineup.OfferedList.length != 0}">{{zone.Lineup.OfferedList.toString()}}</span>
                <span ng-class="{'lineup break' : zone.Lineup.BreakList.length != 0}">{{zone.Lineup.BreakList.toString()}}</span>
                <span ng-class="{'lineup stc' : zone.Lineup.STCList.length != 0}">{{zone.Lineup.STCList.toString()}}</span>
              </div>
            </div> ...
```

I have tried ng-if, ng-hide, track by, etc. but nothing seems to work.
Here's the CSS I am using to create the bubbles.

```
.lineup{
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
}
.free {
  color: #00b140;
}
.loaded{
  color: #6b46e5;
}
.accepted{
  color: #0a9dc7;
}

.offered{
  color: deeppink;
}

.break{
  color: orangered;
}

.STC{
  color: saddlebrown;
}
```

I expect the bubbles to appear only when the text is there. Moreover, when the sort order is changed by the user it should not go blank for over 2 seconds then render the template. 
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-if` with `ng-repeat`, pipe to a filter:

> SLOW
>
> ```
> <ion-item class="item no-border no-padding dark-bg"
>           ng-repeat="zone in $root.zones track by zone.zoneName"
>           ng-if="checkVisibility(zone.zoneName)">
> ```

## Faster

```
<ion-item class="item no-border no-padding dark-bg"
          ng-repeat="zone in zones | filter : zoneFilter track by zone.zoneName">
```

```
$scope.zoneFilter = function(item) {
     return $scope.checkVisibility(item);
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Changing 
`zone.Lineup.FreeList.length != 0` to `zone.Lineup.FreeList.length > 0` solved the bubble problem.